# Proper Place to Bind Object to Element

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-next

[Data Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) are a safe place to store strings onto a DOM element, because you're guaranteed that your property-naming will never collide with a future property that gets added to the DOM specification.

However, what if you want to bind a non-JSON javascript object to an DOM element as a property?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bind Custom Object to DOM Element</title>
    <style>
            div{ border: solid #333333 1vmin; padding:1vmin; 
                display:inline-block; font-size:4vmin}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function main()
        {
            let obj = {}
            obj.name = "Lonnie";

            let div = document.createElement("div");
            div.textContent = "Click Me";
            div.myCustomObject = obj;
            div.addEventListener('click',function()
            {
                alert(this.myCustomObject.name);
            });
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        }
        window.addEventListener('load', main);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Data attributes are designed to hold strings, not objects. Is it ok to use them for nonJSON object-properties, or does the specification recommend a different location for adding object-properties to DOM nodes?

Comment: I dont think HTMLElements are supposed to hold your state. Why not create a `Map` of element ids and your custom objects. In your event handler you can retrieve the state by the elements id.

Comment: That’s not a data attribute, it’s an [expando](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Expando). And… I still don’t know the answer to this! (But yes, if you can rely on `WeakMap` support, it’s equivalent.)

Comment: @Reijo I understand that this can be done with a Map. My question remains.

Comment: @LonnieBest Are you asking for permission then? Of Course you can expand an element with your own properties, but why would you do that, if you can use Map or WeakMap or any state management solution that is proven to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm mainly hoping that someone can direct me to a place, in specification, that formally addresses the avoidance of "future naming collision" when you actually do add an object-property to a DOM node (in the same way that `data attributes` address this for string-based properties added to DOM nodes). The ability to do this isn't going away, so I was hoping that there was a more formally certain way to avoid future naming collision other than "unlikely future property" naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Data attributes are designed to hold strings, not objects.

But you are not using attributes. Therefore you can store everything you want under a regular property.

> Is it ok to use them for nonJSON object-properties,

Sure.

> or does the specification recommend a different location for adding object-properties to DOM nodes?

No, it does not. the DOM spec is language neutral, therefore it doesn't really describe how objects in JS behave that implement that spec.

Comment: I realize that I'm not using data attributes in my example, but what I'm wanting to know is: are data attributes also indented for circumstances like shown in my example. And, if not, does the spec formally address how one should avoid future naming collisions for custom-object-properties on DOM nodes. I've never seen this exact topic addressed in specification.

Comment: data attributes may only contain strings. For sure there can be collisions.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a WeakMap solution using ES6:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bind Custom Object to DOM Element</title>
    <style>
            div{ border: solid #333333 1vmin; padding:1vmin; 
                display:inline-block; font-size:4vmin}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        async function main()
        {
            let obj = {}
            obj.name = "Lonnie";
            let obj2 = {}
            obj2.name = "Mark"

            let div = document.createElement("div");
            div.textContent = "Click Me";
            div.myCustomObject = obj;

            const wm = new WeakMap();

            wm.set(div, obj);
            wm.set(div, obj2);
            console.log(wm.get(div)); // "my value"

            div.addEventListener('click',function()
            {
                alert(wm.get(div).name);
            });
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        }
        window.addEventListener('load', main);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This method ensures there are no clashes between property names.

Personally I don’t see any issue with binding it to an attribute however and there doesn’t seem to be any advice against doing so, it’s the data attributes that are meant to contain strings